# Change the background with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the background of a div with a function from an external javascript file.

#### This is the css for the div:

```
#astronaut{
    background:url(MaedchenInRakate.png) no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:380px;
    top:400px;
    left:500px;
    z-index:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation:mymove 30s infinite ;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 30s infinite;/*Safari and Chrome*/ 
    -moz-animation:mymove 30s infinite ; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-animation:mymove 30s infinite ;  
}
```

#### And the function which should change the background:

```
function rakete() {
    if(geschlecht == "w") {
        alert("Maedchen");
    } else if(geschlecht == "m") {  
        document.getElementById("astronaut").style.background = "url('Junge_InRakete.png')";
    } 
}
```

---

#### The function is called after checking the form:

```
function pruefeFormular() {
    var f = document.forms[0];

    if(f.elements["Vorname"].value == "") {
        alert("Du hast keinen Namen eingegeben!");
    } else if(!f.elements["Geschlecht"][0].checked && !f.elements["Geschlecht"][1].checked) {
        alert("Gib bitte an, ob Du ein Mädchen oder Junge bist");
    } else if(f.elements["Planet"].options[f.elements["Planet"].selectedIndex].value == "") {
        alert("Bitte wähle einen Planeten aus!");
    } else {
        geschlechtSp();
        reiseziel(f.elements["Planet"].options[f.elements["Planet"].selectedIndex].value);
        rakete();
    }
}
```

---

I also tried:

```
 document.getElementById("astronaut").style.background = "url(Junge_InRakete.png)";
```

With only double quote. The global variables are also ok. Has anybody a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("astronaut").style.backgroundImage = "url('Jungle_InRakete.png')";
```

Comment: Although it´s similar to background, it works now with backgroundImage. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line

```
 document.getElementById("astronaut").style.backgroundImage = "url('Junge_InRakete.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this once:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeBackdrop(toWhat) {
        document.getElementById("backDrop").style.background = "url('images/" + toWhat + ".jpg')";
    }
    changeBackdrop("bg_blueberries");
</script>
```